# Alert protocol in TLS

Tags: tls

Assuming the alert protocol is encrypted AFTER a session has been established and the structure below, how does the client know whether to expect encrypted data or not?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Alert_protocol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch from plain to encrypted is marked by a special record type called `change_cipher_spec` (which is neither `handshake`, `alert` or `application_data`); it is unambiguous. Plus, the moment the switch occurs is quite clear from the client point of view, given the previous handshake messages.

If unsure, have a look at the actual [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246), which is quite clear (for a standard). [This answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-work/20847#20847) can serve as an introduction.